# I got error on while building express.js app with pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

When I searched url:http://localhost:3000/users/edit-profile 
the page returns

> Error: Failed to lookup view "User Detail" in views directory
>   "C:\Users\SuJinKim\Documents\WeTube1\views"
>       at Function.render (C:\Users\SuJinKim\Documents\WeTube1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
>       at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\SuJinKim\Documents\WeTube1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
>       at userDetail (C:\Users\SuJinKim\Documents\WeTube1\controllers/userController.js:5:45)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\SuJinKim\Documents\WeTube1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\SuJinKim\Documents\WeTube1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\SuJinKim\Documents\WeTube1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\SuJinKim\Documents\WeTube1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\Users\SuJinKim\Documents\WeTube1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at param (C:\Users\SuJinKim\Documents\WeTube1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
>       at param (C:\Users\SuJinKim\Documents\WeTube1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)

I thought it's because of order of routers but.. it didn'work

I even don't have User Detail on my codes and pug files...

this is my main app.js

```
    import "core-js"
    import express from "express";
    import morgan from "morgan";
    import helmet from "helmet"
    import bodyParser from "body-parser";
    import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
    import { localsMiddleware } from "./middlewares";
    import globalRouter from "./routers/globalRouter"
    import userRouter from "./routers/userRouter";
    import videoRouter from "./routers/videoRouter"
    import routes from "./routes"
    const app = express();

    app.set("view engine", "pug");
    app.use(helmet());
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
    app.use(morgan("dev"));
    app.use(localsMiddleware)

    app.use("/", globalRouter);
    app.use(routes.users, userRouter);
    app.use(routes.videos, videoRouter);



    export default app;
```

this is my userRouter.js

```
    import express from "express";
    import routes from "../routes";
    import { userDetail, editProfile, changePassword } from "../controllers/userController";

    const userRouter = express.Router();

    userRouter.get(routes.editProfile, editProfile);
    userRouter.get(routes.changePassword, changePassword);
    userRouter.get(routes.userDetail, userDetail);

    export default userRouter;
```

this is my userController.js

```
    export const join = (req, res) => res.render("join", { pageTitle: "Join"});
    export const login = (req, res) => res.render("login", { pageTitle: "Login"});
    export const logout = (req, res) => res.render("logout", { pageTitle: "Logout"});
    export const userDetail = (req, res) => res.render("userDetail", { pageTitle: "User Detail"});
    export const editProfile = (req, res) => res.render("editProfile", { pageTitle: "Edit Profile"});
    export const changePassword = (req, res) => res.render("changePassword", { pageTitle: "Change 
    Password"});
```

and this is my routes.js

```
    // Global
    const HOME = "/";
    const JOIN = "/join";
    const LOGIN = "/login";
    const LOGOUT = "/logout";
    const SEARCH = "/search";

    // Users
    const USERS = "/users";
    const USER_DETAIL = "/:id";
    const EDIT_PROFILE = "/edit-profile";
    const CHANGE_PASSWORD = "/change-password";

    // Videos
    const VIDEOS = "/videos";
    const UPLOAD = "/upload"
    const VIDEO_DETAIL = "/:id";
    const EDIT_VIDEO = "/:id/edit"
    const DELETE_VIDEO = "/:id/delete"

    const routes = {
        home: HOME,
        join: JOIN,
        login: LOGIN,
        logout: LOGOUT,
        search: SEARCH,
        users: USERS,
        userDetail: USER_DETAIL,
        editProfile: EDIT_PROFILE,
        changePassword: CHANGE_PASSWORD,
        videos: VIDEOS,
        upload: UPLOAD,
        videoDetail: VIDEO_DETAIL,
        editVideo: EDIT_VIDEO,
        deleteVideo: DELETE_VIDEO
      };

      export default routes;
```

as you can see there is no "User Detail" constant or variable.
I can't find what's wrong with it...
it would me really appreciate with your help!

Here are pug files in views folder.. In views there are `changePassword.pug, deleteVieo.pug, editProfile.pug, home.pug, join.pug, login.pug, logout.pug, search.pug, upload.pug, userDetail.pug, videoDetail.pug.`

Comment: I don't see  `app.set('views', './views')` in your `app.js` could be the issue.

Comment: It's same as ````app.set("view engine", "pug");```` However, It works well on macOS but not on Window. It was first built on macOS. I think the problem is os when i builded it

Comment: There's at least one typo in your list of pug files in the view folder (`deleteVieo.pug`), so are you sure that `userDetail.pug` exists in that folder?  This error would be thrown when the pug engine can't find that file.

Comment: Yes, It is. and  it works well on macOs but not on Window10